# Is there any way to access the user tables on drupal?

Tags: users

I want to ask where the information about users is saved in the database, since I could not find any corresponding entries in the sql file. I would like to share the user tables with another CMS, namely question2answer.com, so I do not have to maintain two user databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users are saved in the database table 'users'.

Comment: Sorry, I feel dump. I thought I looked for it, but fo r sure, it is there...